# com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, apk

This issue occurs when I'm trying to build APK. Otherwise, when I'm running the application it runs without any issue.

Here's the logcat for details:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageGeneralQaDebug'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > java.io.IOException: Failed to create '/Users/muhammad/Documents/Example/app/build/outputs/apk/appGeneralQa/debug/example.apk'
   > A failure occurred while executing

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

simillar issue....

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33744000)